# Create NonUniformImage based on Numpy 2d array with custom cell width and height

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a "heatmap" with Matplotlib of a 2d Numpy Array and found the NonUniformImage option [here](https://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/examples/pylab_examples/image_nonuniform.html). Below is a simple single version. Unfortunately I'm not able to change the x without changing the y. The error that pyhton Propmpts is: `Axes don't match array shape`

### Reproducible Example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.image import NonUniformImage
from matplotlib import cm

x = np.arange(6)
y = np.arange(6)
z = x[:, np.newaxis].dot(y[:, np.newaxis].transpose())

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = NonUniformImage(ax, interpolation='nearest', extent=(0, len(x)-1, 0, len(y)-1))
im.set_data(x, y, z)
ax.images.append(im)
ax.set_xlim(0, len(x)-1)
ax.set_ylim(0, len(y)-1)
```

My goal is to plot a map based on a Numpy 2d array with 'custom Grid cells'. That means that I can assign x and y with irregular series (e.g. `np.array([0.5,3,8,15,15.4])`. I know the x and y that are assign represent the center of a cell so the last thing I would like to solve is that the plot is completely visible (if that is possible).

How can I make a image that has a different constraint (not square), with custom width and height depending on two lists?

Comment: When I run your code I get [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrgeV.png). Is this not what you want? Or do you get a different result?

Comment: No I got the same result but I can only create images with the same dimensions (e.g. 6x6, 8x8 or 21x21). I would like to make an image of 60 x 29 and have custom height and width depending on to lists. I changed the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you made a mistake defining `z`. Possibly what you're after is

```
x = np.arange(6)
y = np.arange(8)
z = x[np.newaxis,:] * y[:, np.newaxis]
print(z.shape)
```

such that the shape is (8,6).